# Gradient Descent Octave Code

Tags: machine-learning, octave, gradient-descent

need help in completing this function. Getting an error while trying to find out derJ :

```
error: X(0,_): subscripts must be either integers 1 to (2^63)-1 or logicals
```

My code:

```
function [theta, J_history] = gradientDescent (X, y, theta, alpha, num_iters)
    m         = length (y);   % number of training examples
    J_history = zeros (num_iters, 1);

    for iter = 1 : num_iters
        predictions = X * theta;   % hypothesis

        % derivative term for cost function
        derJ = (1 / m) * sum ( (predictions - y) * X(iter-1, 2) );

        % updating theta values
        theta           = theta - (alpha * derJ);
        J_history(iter) = computeCost (X, y, theta);
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code states `X(iter - 1, 2)`, but in your for loop `iter` starts from `1`.

Therefore in the very first iteration, `X(iter - 1, 2)` will evaluate to `X(0,2)`, and `0` is not a valid index in matlab.